# Refactor PostgreSQL query to return percents instead of count

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE survey_results (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    scores jsonb DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone  
);
```

I get data from this table with following query:

```
SELECT
  date(survey_results.created_at),
  json_build_object(
    'high', COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,food_insecurity}' in('high'))),
    'medium', COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,food_insecurity}' in('medium'))),
    'low', COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,food_insecurity}' in('low')))
  ) as food_insecurity,

  json_build_object(
    'high', COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,motivation}' in('high'))),
    'medium', COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,motivation}' in('medium'))),
    'low', COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,motivation}' in('low')))
  ) as motivation                               
  FROM survey_results
  GROUP BY date(survey_results.created_at);
```

I wanted to refactor this query to return percents of records instead of count. How can I do this? Here is sql fiddle that You can experiment with.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5a86e/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can always math it out](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/dae8b/25/0):

```
SELECT
  date(survey_results.created_at),
  json_build_object(
    'high', ROUND(COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,food_insecurity}' in('high'))) * 1.0 / COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,food_insecurity}' in('high','medium','low'))) * 100,2),
    'medium', ROUND(COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,food_insecurity}' in('medium'))) * 1.0 / COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,food_insecurity}' in('high','medium','low'))) * 100,2),
    'low', ROUND(COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,food_insecurity}' in('low'))) * 1.0 / COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,food_insecurity}' in('high','medium','low'))) * 100,2)
  ) as food_insecurity,
  json_build_object(
    'high', ROUND(COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,motivation}' in('high'))) * 1.0 / COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,motivation}' in('high','medium','low'))) * 100,2),
    'medium', ROUND(COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,motivation}' in('medium'))) * 1.0 / COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,motivation}' in('high','medium','low'))) * 100,2),
    'low', ROUND(COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,motivation}' in('low'))) * 1.0 / COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,motivation}' in('high','medium','low'))) * 100,2)
) as motivation                               
FROM survey_results
GROUP BY date(survey_results.created_at);
```

You can adjust the rounding and filter however you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do:

```
'high', AVG(CASE WHEN scores#>>'{medic,categories,food_insecurity}' in (' high') THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END),
```

Or to be a bit more cryptic:

```
'high', AVG( (scores#>>'{medic,categories,food_insecurity}' in (' high'))::int),
```

Comment: The first one not works: `ERROR: syntax error at or near "THEN" Position: 150`, the second one also not works: `ERROR: cannot cast type boolean to numeric Position: 141`

Comment: @MateuszUrbański . . . I don't know where the `number` came from.  It is not a valid Postgres type.